# Intuition behind expectation formula - summing to get an average?

Tags: probability, statistics, intuition, expected-value

When I was introduced to the concept of expected value, I learnt it as an extension of the calculation of arithmetic mean (I will illustrate this process below).

*-Start of illustration-*

Suppose two fair coins are tossed 6 times and X is the number of heads that occur per toss of the 2 coins - then the values of X are 0, 1 and 2. Suppose that the experiment yields 0 heads, 1 head and 2 head a total of 1, 3, and 2 times respectively. Then the average number of heads per toss of the two coins is then:

$\displaystyle \frac{(0)(1)+(1)(3)+(2)(2)}{6} \approx 1.17$ (3 s.f.)

We can then re-express the LHS as

$\displaystyle (0)(\frac{1}{6})+(1)(\frac{3}{6})+(2)(\frac{2}{6})$

Recognising that the fractions $\displaystyle \frac{1}{6}, \frac{3}{6}, \frac{2}{6}$ are the relative frequencies for the different values of X in the experiment, this was generalised to lead up to the formula for expectation (at least for discrete random variables):

$E(X)= \sum_{\text{all }x} x \cdot P(X=x)$

*-End of illustration-*

I could understand the derivation of the formula, but am slightly uncomfortable with the concept of "adding things up to get an average" - intuitively, we need to add things up AND divide things up to get an average value. I understand that, in the expectation formula, this division is implicitly embedded given the fact that we are multiplying each value by its probability (which is a fraction, and contains the "division" in the denominator). Nevertheless, the counter-intuitive idea of "adding up all the possible values" (albeit multiplying each by their probability of occurring) just does not seem comfortable. Addition should not give an average! This discomfort is compounded by the fact that expectation is called the "weighted average", not the "weighted sum" (or at least, far less commonly). If the emphasis is on summation, why don't we call it "weighted sum"?

Would really appreciate the advice of anyone who can help me see why "addition can give average" in an intuitive manner, or at least, comment on my confusion, thank you!

Comment: I introduce my students to this by having them look at how I compute grades in my syllabus. I still call it a weighted average because... well, that's what it does.

Comment: An unweighted average is just a weighted average where all the weights are equal to $1/n.$ Summing and then dividing by $n$ is the same thing as doing a weighted average where all the weights are equal to $1/n.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen then let's call it a "weighted sum" then, rather than "weighted average" - because it clearly is ultimately a sum. A weighted sum where the weight attached to each value is (1/n) [contrast this with the sentence "a weighted average where the weight attached to each value is (1/n)].

Comment: @DaphnaKeidar could not tag you in the previous comment, so hope you don't mind if I tag you in a separate one; my response to you is the same as to spaceisdarkgreen.

Comment: You're absolutely right that a weighted average should involve a division by the sum of the weights. What do you think is the sum of the weights in this case?

Comment: @Charlz97 Okay... then a weighted average is a "weighted sum" where all the weights add up to one. "Weighted sum" suggests no special condition on the sum of the weights.

Comment: @Charlz97 Or, equivalently, we divide by the sum of the weights at the end to turn the weighted sum into a weighted average. Dividing all the weights by that sum makes them add up to one... it's the same thing. As Rahul suggests, in your example you can put a $\sum_x P(X=x)$ in the denominator if you really want, but that's just a fancy way of writing $1.$

Comment: @Rahul the sum of the weights is 1. So you're saying there is an "unwritten denominator" in the expectation formula, dividing the expression by 1?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen that makes more sense to me now! Because the concept of "division" should be explicitly present in the formula, like what you mentioned about including the denominator.

Comment: @Charlz97 I don't know that it "should" cause there's more than one way to think about things, but glad it makes more sense now.

Comment: I think of it more as "there is no need to have a denominator"; after all, we *define* probabilities to necessarily sum to 1. But if your sense of justice prevents you from accepting an average without a denominator, then by all means think of it as a denominator that's somehow "really there" but just unwritten.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? Its score was -3 as of a minute ago. This question is fine; it doesn't deserve those downvotes.

Comment: @littleO Thank you! I've no idea too, I'm just trying to clarify doubts.

Comment: @Charlz97 Are you aware that answers can be accepted $\left(\color{limegreen}{\checkmark}\right)$? Accepting an answer shows that you appreciate the effort of the respondents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable and the possible values of $X$ are $x_1, \ldots, x_m$. Let $p_i = P(X=x_i)$ for $i = 1, \ldots, m$.

Imagine that we repeat our random experiment $N$ times, each time observing a new value of $X$. We would like to predict the average of all these observed values of $X$. Let $N_i$ be the number of trials for which $X = x_i$. Then the average of the observed values of $X$ is
$$ 
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^m N_i x_i = \sum_{i=1}^m x_i \frac{N_i}{N}.
$$
But we would predict that $N_i/N$ will be equal to $p_i$. So, it seems reasonable to predict that the average of the observed values of $X$ will be equal to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m x_i p_i.
$$
This motivates the definition of the expected value of $X$. (Maybe we should really call it the "long run average value" of $X$, or just the average value of $X$.)